# Subir un archivo al servidor, limitando las extensiones y tipo de archivo

Tags: php, file, upload, type

Con `$_FILES["files"]["type"]` puedo subir archivos `pdf`, pero estoy tratando de especificar que acepte también archivos `.ai` (*illustrator*) y otras posibles extensiones, pero no consigo como hacerlo.

Y habrá alguna manera de visualizarlo en mi pagina, como se hace con los archivos pdf?

**Mi código:**

```
 if($_FILES["files"]["type"][$i]=="application/pdf" || $_FILES["files"]["type"][$i]=="application/ai") {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para validar tu extensión `AI` illustrator puedes usar `application/postscript`.

*Un posible ejemplo:*

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['sumb'])) {

    //Obtenemos imagen.
    $file = $_FILES["files"];
    $file_name = $file["name"];         
    $file_type = $file["type"];

    //Comprobamos la extensión.         
    if ($file_type != "application/pdf" && $file_type != "application/postscript") {
        echo "Tu extensión no es valido";
    } else {
        echo 'Tu extensión es valido';
    }
}
?>      

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files" />
    <input type="submit" name="sumb" value="Cargar" />
</form>
```

A tu segunda pregunta, como mostrar un `PDF` en un `iframe`.

*Podrías crear algo así:*

```
<object data="ruta_pdf" type="application/pdf">
    <embed src="ruta_pdf" type="application/pdf" />
</object>
```

Fuente [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654577/html-embedded-pdf-iframe).

Comment: listo, eso era... ahora habrá alguna manera de visualizar el archivo .ai(illustrator) en un iframe o embled ?

Comment: Eduardo, te he dejado un posible ejemplo, cómo mostrar tu `PDF`. Espero verte ayudado, Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

La primera pregunta se resuelve de una manera simple:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="nombre_campo" type="file" accept="token_tipos_aceptados"
    multiple="1" /><!-- 1 para indicar que acepta varios archivos -->
    <input type="submit" name="btncargar" value="Cargar" />
</form>
```

Dónde `token_tipos_aceptados` debe ser una cadena espacio-separada de identificadores de tipos de archivo admitidos, conforme con la [especificación html recomendada por W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/SPSD-html5-20180327/single-page.html#file-upload-state-(type=file)). Cuando se haga click en explorar para buscar los archivos a cargar el explorador sólo mostrará archivos de los tipos indicados.

Si se especifica `multiple=1` el navegador aceptará cargar varios archivos simultáneamente en un sólo elemento input. Pero, se debe tener cuidado porque la superglobal $_FILES los pasa con un formato de arreglo bastante diferente del usual.